# How do I filter rows on a subset of columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

Tail of df:

```
          fruit Letter Points     A    B     C       D
16       cherry      P   7876 11.43 7.23 13.72 4.29.01
17 chili pepper      Q   7831 10.85 7.18 14.14 4.33.90
18   clementine      R   7827 11.07 7.24 14.19 4.56.52
19   cloudberry      S   7704 10.38 7.73 14.32       X
20      coconut      T   7634 11.21 7.12 13.25 4.57.92
21    cranberry      U   7346 10.88 6.65 13.80 4.32.50
```

This seems like a common question but all the answers I've seen are based on filtering either over one column or over all columns. Here, I want to remove rows which contain "X" in **only** columns A to D.

Based on previous answers, if I wanted to only filter on one column, I can do:

`df <- df[!grepl("X", df$D),]`

Which works fine, but I can only do this manually as I know *a priori* where the "X" is. As I want to filter on many dfs of the same format, I need a way to filter on columns A to D.

Intuitively I figured I could just expand the argument in grepl to include the columns I want to filter on:

`df <- df[!grepl("X", df[,c("A","B","C","D")]),]` or
`df1 <- df1[!grepl("X", df1[,4:7]),]`

However this ends up removing rows which don't contain an "X", let alone a letter in the A-D cols. I'm guessing this is because the grep family of functions don't accept multiple vectors?

Ideally I'd like a base solution as I'm stumped at something which should be easy to figure out.

Full df:

```
df <- structure(list(fruit = c("apple", "apricot", "avocado", "bell pepper", 
"bilberry", "blackberry", "blood orange", "blueberry", "boysenberry", 
"canary melon", "cantaloupe", "cherimoya", "chili pepper", "clementine", 
"cloudberry", "cranberry"), Letter = c("A", "B", "C", "E", "F", 
"G", "I", "J", "K", "M", "N", "O", "Q", "R", "S", "U"), Points = c(8900, 
8757, 8742, 8554, 8531, 8461, 8206, 8153, 8113, 8106, 8050, 8017, 
7831, 7827, 7704, 7346), A = c("10.54", "10.64", "10.69", "10.64", 
"10.76", "10.99", "10.81", "11.00", "10.84", "11.05", "10.72", 
"10.84", "10.85", "11.07", "10.38", "10.88"), B = c("8.03", "7.88", 
"7.78", "7.24", "7.92", "7.59", "7.68", "7.32", "7.37", "7.34", 
"7.18", "6.89", "7.18", "7.24", "7.73", "6.65"), C = c("16.68", 
"15.19", "14.14", "15.72", "14.50", "14.75", "15.64", "14.19", 
"15.09", "15.10", "14.66", "14.20", "14.14", "14.19", "14.32", 
"13.80"), D = c("4.42.33", "4.35.06", "4.35.59", "4.23.13", "4.23.23", 
"4.29.93", "4.48.64", "4.21.06", "4.30.12", "4.52.35", "5.00.38", 
"4.48.11", "4.33.90", "4.56.52", "X", "4.32.50")), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
21L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `df[!grepl('X',do.call(paste,df[4:7])),]`

Answer (score 0):

We could loop through the columns of interest, check whether the values are equal to `"X"` (based on the data, it is an exact match), then `Reduce` the `list` of logical `vector`s to a single `vector` with `|` and use that to subset the data

```
df[!Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[c("A", "B", "C", "D")], `==`, "X")),]
```

or with `grepl` (if it is not an exact)

```
df[!Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[c("A", "B", "C", "D")], grepl, pattern = "X")),]
```

---

or use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   filter_at(vars(A:D), any_vars(!grepl('X', .)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the structure of your data:

```
df[!grepl('X',do.call(paste,df[4:7])),]
```

should work.

If at all you have other values like `23X.4` for example and you want to maintain them, then you can use regex as shown below:

```
df[!grepl('(?m)^X$',do.call(paste,c(sep='\n',df[4:7])),perl = T),]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cols = c("A",  "B", "C", "D")
df[! rowSums(df[cols] == "X"), ]
```

This will remove rows from `df` where the value in any of `cols`  *is* `"X"` (not *contains `"X"`*, as some other answers are doing).

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr to remove any rows where the value in any of the columns A, B, C or D is equal to 'X' looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
filter_at(df, vars(A:D), any_vars(!. == 'X'))
```

Comment: It looks like you were matching on 'X' appearing anywhere in the string, rather than matching on 'X' directly.